# Dismiss react error messages after a timeout

Tags: reactjs, twilio-programmable-chat, tsx

I am trying to display some react error messages and hide them after a timeout of 5 seconds. Below is the code:

```
import * as React from 'react'
import {ErrorInfo} from '../Twilio/api'
export const Error = ({type, message, visible}: ErrorInfo) => (
    // visible=true,
    setTimeout(function () {
        visible = false
    }, 5000),
        visible ?
            <div>
                <p>
                    <strong>{type}:</strong> {message}
                    <br/>
                    <small>
                        UI version: <code>{GLOBAL_VERSION}</code>
                    </small>
                </p>
            </div> : <span/>
)
```

`ErrorInfo` is as follows:

```
export type ErrorInfo = {
    type: string
    message: string
    visible: boolean
}
```

However, `visible` is being set to undefined and therefore error message is not getting displayed. If I set it to true while exporting `Error`, then it is getting displayed by the `Header` element is not getting removed when `visible` becomes false.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you'd want to control the `visible` state in your `Error` component.

And then, you can use `useEffect` to hide the error after 5 secs (with proper cleanup)

```
export const Error = ({ type, message }: ErrorInfo) => {
   const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false)
   useEffect(() => {
     // message is empty (meaning no errors). Adjust as needed
     if(!message){
      setIsVisible(false)
      return
     }
     // error exists. Display the message and hide after 5 secs
     setIsVisible(true)
     const timer = setTimeout(() => {
       setIsVisible(false)
     }, 5000);
     return () => clearTimeout(timer);
   }, [message]) // executes every time `message` changes. Adjust as needed
   if(!visible) return null
   return (
      <div>
        <p>
            <strong>{type}:</strong> {message}
            <br />
            <small>
                UI version: <code>{GLOBAL_VERSION}</code>
            </small>
        </p>
    </div>
   )
}
```

Comment: I knew that I have to use state, but did not know the syntax being new to tsx with react :/

Answer (score 2):

You should use state.  Something like this:

```
export default function App() {
  const [visible, setIsVisible] = React.useState(false);

  setTimeout(function() {
    setIsVisible(true);
  }, 5000);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      {visible && <p>Will show in 5 seconds</p>}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Check out a demo [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-dewdney-8kk3h?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)