# How to use setTimeout function in condition statement?

Tags: reactjs

I want to show `alert` that message was sent (202) or has errors (else) on screen but this message should be clean after 3 seconds.

I usually use it only in `useEffect` hook, but I want it put in a condition

```
if (res.status === 200) {         
    setTimeout(function() {
        setStatus('success')   
    }, 1000);
```

Update:

I tried suggested snippets of code, but not working. Solution with `[res...]` cause a error, because react do not see variable like that. I go forward with this code, adding in if statement new variable which is associated with res... but still not work

```
      useEffect(() => {

        const timer =  ""
    

        if (kupa === "sukces") {         
          const timer =  setTimeout(function() {
          setStatus('success')   }, 1000); 
         
      }
      if (kupa === "error") {         
        const timer =    setTimeout(function() {
              setStatus('error')   }, 1000); 
             }
              return () => clearTimeout(timer);

      },  [kupa]);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dismiss react error messages after a timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61625297/dismiss-react-error-messages-after-a-timeout)

Comment: you can't dismiss browser alert('something') window as it passes control to the user and your code can only wait for he/she to close it.

Comment: change kupa from useEffect dependency to be [status]. also "sukces" in the condition to be "success"

Answer (score 0):

I think you can add the condition inside **useEffect** and based on the **res.status** the component will be **re-render**. if the **res.status === 200** then **setStatus('success')** will be updated.

```
useEffect(() => {
if (res.status === 200) {         
    setTimeout(function() {
        setStatus('success')   
    }, 1000);
 }
}, [res.status])
```

Comment: here's a [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-blackwell-tjqe16?file=/src/App.js) for your code.

Comment: Be careful using timeouts. Clear the timeout in the return statement of the useEffect, otherwise the code runs even after the component unmounts.

Comment: @Shah Thanks for notifying me. noted

Answer (score -1):

Try this one:

```
useEffect(() => {
        
    

        if (kupa === "sukces") {         
          
          setStatus('success')   
      }
      if (kupa === "error") {         
       
              setStatus('error')   
             }

         
              
                return () => {  setTimeout(function() {
                  setStatus('')  
                setKupa('') }, 3000); 
   }
               
                

      },  [kupa] );
```